# How to access graph api in swagger?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, swagger

net core project. My requirement is as follows. I have webapi project in .net core and swagger. I have created two apps in azure ad. Now I have authorize button in swagger. I want to do authorization as below. If the user is belongs to any group whose name starting with AP I want to authorize those users. To be frank, I bit confused here. Now I have two apps in azure. Whenever I get token through swagger/swagger app in azure AD, same token can be used to hit my apis? I will show my implementation.

Below is my appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "TenantId": "organizations",
    "ClientId": "my web api azure ad app client id",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Swagger": {
    "ClientId": "my swagger app azure ad app client id",
    "ClientSecret": "my secrete",
       "AuthorizationUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    "TokenUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token"
  }
```

Below is my startup

```
      services
                       .AddAuthentication(o =>
                       {
                           o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                       })
                       .AddJwtBearer(o =>
                       {
                           o.Authority = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.Authority;
                           o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                           o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                           {

                               ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                               {
                                  azureActiveDirectoryOptions.AppIdUri,
                                  azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId
                               },
                               ValidateIssuer = true,
                               ValidateAudience = true,
                               ValidIssuer = "https://myorg.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/default",
                               RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,


                           };
                       });
      services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

                    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                    {
                        Type = "oauth2",
                        Flow = "implicit",
                        AuthorizationUrl = swaggerUIOptions.AuthorizationUrl,
                        TokenUrl = swaggerUIOptions.TokenUrl,
                        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                              {"User.read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.read" }
                        }
                    });
                    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                    {
                            { "oauth2", new[] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" } }
                    });
  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("APGroupsOnly", policy =>
                       policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupsCheckRequirement("YourGroupID")));
            });
```

Below is configure method.

```
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
                c.OAuthClientId(swaggerUIOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthClientSecret(swaggerUIOptions.ClientSecret);
                c.OAuthRealm(azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthAppName("Swagger");
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

This is my implementation for requirement. Whenever I run swagger I get token. Now I want to use this token to call graph api. After getting group details I wan to hit my api. Now my confusion is, I m getting token in swagger/swagger app so same token can it be used to obtain group details and authorize apis? Can someone guide me on this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you simplify the question? Is it that you want to call Graph API from 2 APPs using the same token?

Comment: Hi Prashant. I want to implement authorisation using groups. My client is swagger. I have two apps in azure ad for swagger and we api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, currently you have:

1. Swagger/Swagger app, which I think your clients will use to access your API. I will call it as client app. There is an app (APP-Client) registered in your AAD for it, and user will get access token with the app.
2. Your Web API server, which is protected with AAD (APP-Server) and accepts users' requests.

---

And the workflow is:

1). A user gets a token (Token-For-API) in Swagger app (with APP-Client).

2). The user call your app with token (Token-For-API).

3). Your API will call Graph API for the user, and return back the result.

---

At present, you have no problem with step 1) and 2). So, next, I may give you some suggestions on 3).

Based on Azure AD developer docs, you can use on-behalf-of flow. Your web API server (daemon application) can use the first token to acquire a new token for accessing Microsoft Graph API or other API.

Here are the steps:

A. You need to add permissions for Graph API for your API in AAD (APP-Server) .

[image]

B. Acquire a new token, and call graph API with new token:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    // Web API app info
    string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
    string tenant = "your tenant name or id, for example: hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";
    string clientId = "The app for your web API: 01801a37-****-****-****-baf08b61c63f";
    string clientSecret = "The secret of the app, OKg1UY/**********u@oao91P.p/";

    // Get the token which a user uses to access your API
    var token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;

    // Get current user info
    var current = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
    string userName = current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null ? current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value : current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;

    // Create user assertion
    UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(token, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",userName);

    // Acquire a token of the user for graph
    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var graph_token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", new ClientCredential(clientId,clientSecret), userAssertion).Result.AccessToken;

    // Call graph
    string graphUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups";

    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graph_token);
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    var result = hc.GetAsync(graphUrl).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    hc.Dispose();

    return Ok(result);
}
```

---

**Finally**, if you want to call more graph API, you just need to add necessary permissions for your Web API app (APP-Server) in AAD. To know which permission is needed, you may refer to specific [API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) . For example, in this case, you want to get user's group information, then you may call [List groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). And then, you need to add at least one of the following permissions:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks you understood requirement correctly. I am implementing this now. Thanks a lot